# How to change WooCommece variation data programmtically

Tags: plugins, php, woocommerce-offtopic

While editing a variable product, you can go to the "variations" tab and edit the data for each variation (such as the SKU). I want to edit this data programmatically. The WC_Product_Variation class does not allow to set the value for those fields, just to get them. Is there another way to set those fields programmatically?

Comment: You could probably use wp_update_post() or update_post_meta() but I'm not sure how WooCommerce stores its post data. Questions about third-party plugins that have their own support forum are off-topic btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you try withup date_post_meta

```
<?php update_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $prev_value ); ?>
```

for example

```
update_post_meta($variation_post_id, '_price', $variation['price']);
update_post_meta($variation_post_id, '_regular_price',$variation['price']);
```